# Capybara/Cucumber In Ruby: stop searching when no more elements exist

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, acceptance-testing

The website I'm testing has a bunch of selected filters ([picture for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXPTp.png)). I'm looping through all of them and closing them like so:

```
When /^each (.+) is clicked$/ do |element|
  page.all("#{element}").each do |element|
    element.click
  end
end
```

This code clicks the close button and closes all the open filters. The problem I'm having is that when I get to the end of the filters, it keeps looking and raises this error:

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
        (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.87)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)
      ./features/step_definitions/ux_steps.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      ./features/step_definitions/ux_steps.rb:21:in `/^each (.+) is clicked$/'
      features/ux.feature:16:in `When each span is clicked'
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sort-block order" id="selectedFilters">
    <a id="Anti-Inflammatory_selectedfilter" href="javascript:void(0)" class="current">Anti-Inflammatory<span class="selectedFilterCross" onclick="selectedFilterFun('selectedFilterText1','Anti-Inflammatory',-1); $(this).parent('a').remove();">X</span></a>
    <a id="Cardiac_selectedfilter" href="javascript:void(0)" class="current">Cardiac<span class="selectedFilterCross" onclick="selectedFilterFun('selectedFilterText1','Cardiac',-1); $(this).parent('a').remove();">X</span></a>
    <a id="Diabetic_selectedfilter" href="javascript:void(0)" class="current">Diabetic<span class="selectedFilterCross" onclick="selectedFilterFun('selectedFilterText1','Diabetic',-1); $(this).parent('a').remove();">X</span></a>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to stop the search once the list of items is empty? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that happens because elements that are on the page when you start looping are removed from the page by clicking. If so, you should be able to fix it by repeatedly searching for clickable elements, clicking the first one you find, and searching again until you don't find any more:

```
When /^each (.+) is clicked$/ do |selector|
  while true
    element = page.first(selector)
    if element
      element.click
    else
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Note that `"#{string}"` is the same as `string`.

Comment: This removes the error, but now it is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Oops, typo. Fixed.

Comment: It's still stuck in an infinite loop. It closes all of the filters, but then keeps looking for more. I added the html to my question for clarity sake.

Comment: Found the issue: there were a bunch of `span` tags on the page, so I added the `within "##{id}" do` to make it only target the ones in the div.

Comment: I apologize, but I am not able to vote as I don't have 15 reputation yet.